# How to create a taxonomy terms dropdrown with Views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I need to achieve a block containing a dropdown list of vocabulary terms (called topics). Each topic describe one or many of the content articles. Each topic which is assigned to no articles should not be displayed. When selecting the topic from a dropdown list a page with assigned articles should be displayed.

It seems like achieving a dropdown list of terms from within a view is harder than expected.

Here my steps:
I created a View with display page and exposed form in block: Yes
I selected the term ID and term Name fields; then I expose the filters as "Operator: Is one of," and I selected all. It seems like nothings happens.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what exactly is your expectation?

Comment: You question is incomplete, what is your requirement?

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches:

**A. Create a View out of Taxonomy Terms with a Page Display.**

For fields add: term id, term name
For filters: Term name (with widgets) and expose the filter

Choose then:

- Dropdown,
- Vocabulary (of your choice)
- Expose this filter to visitors...,
- 'Is one of' then select all terms from the vocabulary
- Remove duplicates

In Views UI, on Advanced Tab

- Exposed form in block: Yes
- Exposed form style: Basic | Settings
- Adjust settings to have autosubmit

**B. Create a View out of Content and choose Taxonomy Terms among fields, similar to above.**

**C. Create a View with Block display from Taxonomy Terms and at Format Tab choose Jump Menu.** If you need to overwrite the Jump Menu path you need to add a custom text field and create your desire path out of Replacement Patterns.

Than select the created custom text field from Jump Menu path settings